# Differential Equation (Falling body with fluid drag square of velocity)

Tags: differential

I recently solved a differential equation for a body in free-fall.
$$\frac{dv}{dt} + \left(\frac km\right)v = g$$

This is first-degree, non-separable with an integrating factor.

However, most physicists know that the fluid drag $\left(\frac km\right)v$ goes as the square of the velocity. The equation takes the form:
$$\frac{dv}{dt} + \left(\frac km\right)v^2 = g$$

How do you solve this equation, and what type is it? It doesn't appear to be a "Bernoulli".

Comment: It is [separable](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/separable.aspx): $\frac{dv}{g-\left(\frac km\right)v^2}= dt$. Integrate both sides.

Comment: Yes @Conifold is right. It is indeed separable. You can use $\int{\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}dx}=\frac{ln(|\frac{x+a}{x-a}|)}{2a}$

Comment: Thank you. I should have caught this. LOL